# Datetime formatGMT 24 hour

Tags: apex, datetime

I'm trying to format a DateTime to 24 hour time but it displays the wrong time between midnight and 1 AM.

```
String created = Datetime.now().formatGMT('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'kk:mm:ss.SSS\'Z\'');
```

shows `2017-06-02T24:55:41.319Z` for 12:55 AM instead of `2017-06-02T00:55:41.319Z`.  Is there a way to get it to display the correct time without modifying the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at **[SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)**. If you want 0 based hours use **`H`**, not **`k`**.

```
H   Hour in day (0-23)
k   Hour in day (1-24)
K   Hour in am/pm (0-11)
h   Hour in am/pm (1-12)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change k to h in string format:

```
String created = Datetime.now().formatGMT('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSS\'Z\'');
```

Comment: Note that lower case `h` corresponds to upper case `K` in whether you want to display 12 or 24.

Comment: @AdrianLarson yes, I've updated

Comment: You missed one.